# Change from if-elif-match to match-case maybe nested

Tags: python

After installing python3.10 I tried to transform all `if-elif-else`, of which you see only a small part, into `match-case`. While for the first `if` I didn't have any problems when I switched to the second one I ran into two problems:

- in the `case` only the OR is expected but not the AND
- it is not possible to do a nested `match-case` or a nested 'case' nor an `if`
  Is there a way to solve the "problem" or should I keep the old code?

  ```
    def strip(self, value, dow, day, holiday):
       if day in holiday:
         match value:
           case 'M': retval = '10-14:30'
           case 'P': retval = '14:30-19'
           case 'E': retval = 'Mos 10-14:30'
           case 'D': retval = 'Mos 14:30-19'
           case 'Y': retval = 'Mos 10-19'
           case 'Z': retval = 'Mix 10-14:30-19'
           case _  : pass

       elif ((dow == 'tue') or (dow == 'wed')) and ((value == 'P') or (value == 'F') or (value == 'B') or (value == 'D')):retval = "14-19"
       elif ((dow == 'thu')) and ((value == 'M') or (value == 'G') or (value == 'A') or (value == 'E')):retval = "14-17"
       elif ((dow == 'thu')) and ((value == 'P') or (value == 'F') or (value == 'B') or (value == 'D')):retval = "17-20"
       elif ((dow == 'fri') or (dow == 'sat')) and ((value == 'P') or (value == 'F') or (value == 'B') or (value == 'D')):retval = "14:30-19"
       ... many others
  ```

Comment: `match/case` is for pattern matching. Although it can be used for simple equality tests, it's not a general purpose replacement for `if/elif`

Comment: Those 2 problems is just a description of advantage `if-else` over `match-case`. Use both in places **where** they give you an advantage

Comment: You can represent some of the latter cases with `match dow,value` and `case ['tue'|'wed', 'P' | 'F' | 'B']` as an example for the first elif.

Comment: @Michael Cao. This sounds interesting. WIll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better to rewrite your conditions. They are to complicated. You can create dictionary with key - retval and value - condition. And loop through this dict to get result.

```
def strip(value, dow, day, holiday):
    retval = ""
    conditions = {
        "14-19": dow in ['tue','wed'] and value in ['P', 'F', 'B', 'D'],
        "14-17": (dow == 'thu' and value == 'M') or (value in ['G', 'A', 'E']),
        "17-20": (dow == 'thu' and value == 'P') or (value in ['F', 'B', 'D']),
        "14:30-19": dow in ['fri', 'sat'] and value in ['P', 'F',  'B', 'D'],
    }
    if day in holiday:
        match value:
            case 'M': retval = '10-14:30'
            case 'P': retval = '14:30-19'
            case 'E': retval = 'Mos 10-14:30'
            case 'D': retval = 'Mos 14:30-19'
            case 'Y': retval = 'Mos 10-19'
            case 'Z': retval = 'Mix 10-14:30-19'
            case _  : pass
    else:
        for key, value in conditions.items():
            if value:
                retval = key
                break
    
    return retval
```

Comment: This is very simple and clean. Thank you